# SP Initiated SSO - ADFS 2.0

Tags: asp.net, saml-2.0, adfs2.0

I've been trying to implement the SP initiated SSO with ADFS 2.0 configuration. But I could not find any solution to do that.

Not sure if the ADFS 2.0 supports the SP initiated SSO. I can see there are some third party libraries to do that but I don't want to use any third party libraries. I just need information on posting SAML request to identity provider and getting the SAML assertion back to the survive provider.

Here Service Provider is my application(asp.net) is and ADFS 2.0 is the Identity Provider.

Any idea how I can achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't ADFS - it's ASP.NET.

.NET has no SAML support. You need a third-party stack.

Refer: [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).

ADFS definitely supports the SP initiated SSO flow.